# ERROR 65 in ARM KEIL 5 (Permissions error)

Tags: embedded, arm, microcontroller, keil, cortex-m

I'm relatively new in ARM Cortex M4 series micro-controller.
When I'm trying to debug a simple project(blinky which easily just blinks a led on and off) using KEIL 5 simulator, I get an error like this:

*** error 65: access violation at 0x400FE608 : no 'read' permission
*** error 65: access violation at 0x400FE608 : no 'write' permission

I searched on internet for a solution, and I get this one:

http://www.keil.com/support/docs/814.htm

But actually it is not easy and not logical to mention all the addresses to which I want to access in my whole code like the method mentioned above.

could anybody suggest something else for me please?

(Actually I get this error with all projects which I intended to simulate so I can't simulate anything).

Here is the simple code which I have been using:

```
#define GCGPIOR (*((int*)0x400FE608))
int main(void) 
{ 
GCGPIOR |= 0x20; 
return 0; 
}
```

and I am using this mc: TM4C1294NCPDT

Comment: Huh? Why would you not want to use the correct solution? You're mapping a _range_, not individual addresses...

Comment: So I have to mention every range of addresses which I want to use?

But why when I download some ready examples the problem persists! should't the people who coded the examples do that already! .. they are official examples, so I think that there is something wrong!

Is this problem in all other IDEs like IAR?

Comment: Most people use real hardware.

Comment: I noticed that, but in every video tutorial which i have already seen, they just wrote the program normally and used the debugger sometimes without changing anything in memory map permissions. It's really so strange! any ideas?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin: No you do not have to mention *every range* - you could just map the entire memory.  However one has to question why you are directly addressing memory outside of the knowledge of the linker?  The access violation report is there to catch errors.  What "*offical examples*"?  Adding links to these, or the actual code to your question would be helpful to your cause.  Have you selected the right device for simulation?  Have you set the memory regions correctly in the *target options* dialog or *linker options scatter file* if you are using one?

Comment: @Clifford: The mapping of the entire memory didn't work .. it gives me :
*** error 129: MapMem - map size truncated to 128MB

This happens when I try to map this range: 0x00000000, 0x0FFFFFFF

I did not understand exactly everything in ur post, but for "official examples", I means the examples which are provided by the vendor of the MC, such as Texas Instrument.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin :  I am pretty sure that you don't have 4Gb of memory on a Cortex-M4!  Your answer w.r.t. examples is unhelpful - you still did not add code or links to the source to your question.  I want to see the actual code that is making direct accesses to memory outside of the linker map, because frankly I doubt it, and that is perhaps your real problem. You are probably asking about fixing a *symptom* when in fact you need to find the real *problem*.

Comment: @Clifford: I just tried easily to enable clock gating on port F, so just one writing process to that register .. sorry but I am not at home so I cannot provide the code now, but it should be correct.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin : I am sure tat it is correct; that is not the point.  The point is to determine that it *is not* making the kind of access that triggers the error so we can start looking for the real cause.  At what point does the access violation occur - the debugger will show you the exact code (possibly at assembler level is there is no source) - you could post that.  What is at address 0x0004?  I would guess the reset stack-pointer address?  If you cannot improve this question, I am minded to down-vote it.

Comment: @Clifford: I did not understand exactly what you want, but I uploaded the project for you.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/n6w5s0j989tbnze/StackOverFlow.zip

Waiting for your help please :-)

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin  I am not going to look at "off-site" code.  It should be possible to post the code causing the access violation *in your question*.  If this code is from a vendor, link to the code on the vendor's site at least.

Comment: @Clifford, I will post the code here :

Comment: #define GCGPIOR (*((int*)0x400FE608))

int main(void)
{
 GCGPIOR |= 0x20;
 return 0;
}

Comment: Edit the question to add relevant detail - StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  The code you have posted has been interpreted and Markdown syntax and rendered incorrectly.  You need `code markup like this`, but you should add it to the question in any case.

Comment: @Clifford, sorry for that, I am new in this site.

I added the code to the main question at the end.

Comment: The code is still incorrect.  GCGPIOR is not an lvalue and cannot be assigned.  Are you sure that should not be `(*((int*)0x400FE608))`

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem with KEIL V5, in a CMSIS project with LPC1768 microcontroller.

When debugging with real microcontroller as target, everything works fine. Debugging with simulator as target, when CMSIS tries to initialize the System core clock I get:

```
*** error 65: access violation at 0x400FC1A0 : no 'write' permission
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this really sample code from the chip vendor?  The definition of GCGPIOR should be `volatile`.

```
#define GCGPIOR (*((volatile int*)0x400FE608)))
```

Have you selected the correct device in the simulator/project configuration? Have you installed the Keil::TM4C_DFP device package and are you using the correct device configuration?

The problem appears to be that the memory map used by the simulator is automatically set up from the linker memory map.  If you make direct memory mapped I/O accesses not known to the linker, then it will raise an exception (when this mechanism detects a bug in your code you may be glad of that - it is not a bug in uVision - it is intentional behaviour).

If the MAP command or dialogue did not work for you, Occam's razor suggest to me that you did not perform the operation correctly.  You should map the entire I/O region given in your part's data sheet or user manual.  It may work I suppose if you define the I/O region in the linker scatter file - but that may be getting a bit too complicated.

Comment: Sorry, the address you have seen was just an example, the error is actually happens in the address on which I try to access (in our case 0x400FE608).

And the other simulator config is just default

Comment: about the braces, yes it should be as u mentioned, but it is definetly right in the code, as the error which I have is not in Syntax.
about the rest of your question, the answer of them all is yes.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin : Not being `volatile` is not a syntax error, it is a *semantic* error.  See http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/beginner-s-corner/4023801/Introduction-to-the-Volatile-Keyword for details.  My point is that I cannot believe that either a chip or compiler vendor would provide code examples such as that, and you said it was "offical" (but failed to cite with a link).

Comment: Sorry I didn't noticed volatile .. I meant the brace at the end.
what ever, I tried the code with volatile, but the same error:
*** error 65: access violation at 0x400FE608 : no 'read' permission
*** error 65: access violation at 0x400FE608 : no 'write' permission

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin :  That's a parenthesis `(...)` not a brace `{...}` (or a bracket `[...]` for that matter).

Comment: Ah, thank you for the correction.

Do you have any Idea for my problem? it really annoys!

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin : My suggestion is that the project is configured for different hardware, or that the TM4C_DFP is incomplete and does not include on-chip peripheral simulation, or that you have not used the TM4C_DFP and have it set up for a core Cortex M4 only.  That was kind of implied in the questions I asked that you omitted to answer.

Comment: That is really a stupid problem, as I have no problem with IAR EW, but I would like to work with KEIL, as I feel more relax with it (don't know why).

The bigger problem is that KEIL know about this problem, but they don't care about that as I noticed!

Could you please recheck the link above in my main question, maybe you can find something else.

Comment: The link does not suggest that this is a "problem" - it is intentional behaviour to detect erroneous code.  Which is why I suggest that your configuration is incorrect.  Keil's ARM MDK used ARM's own compiler (Keil are owned by ARM); I would suggest that it is at least a better compiler than IAR's.  In particular it supports ISO C++98 rather then the EC++ subset of IAR.  That said the debugger struggles a bit with some C++ code - especially namespaces (which EC++ does not support of course).

Comment: I do not use the simulator often - I prototype code on Windows with our own RTOS and hardware emulation layer, and test and develop on real hardware, so I am not sure I can help you much further.  If you have a full commercial license for ARM-MDK then you can get support directly from Keil/ARM - just raise a ticket.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54362/discussion-between-clifford-and-mohammed-noureldin).